# flutter: animate transition to named route

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

When I use `Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/someRoute");`, there is a minimal animation which slides in the new route from the bottom of the screen (on Android, might look different on iOS).

How can I add a custom animation to this transition?

I found [this article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/everything-you-need-to-know-about-flutter-page-route-transition-9ef5c1b32823), which has some very neat sample code for **unnamed** routes. They implement their own class which inherits from `PageRouteBuilder` and can be used like this: `Navigator.push(context, SlideRightRoute(page: Screen2()))`. But a `PageRouteBuilder` is not a Widget and can't be registered as a route in `MaterialApp`. So I don't see how to apply this to named routes.

Comment: use `onGenerateRoute` property

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You need to use `onGenerateRoute` in your [`MaterialApp`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html) widget.

```
onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
  if (settings.name == "/someRoute") {
    return PageRouteBuilder(
      settings: settings, // Pass this to make popUntil(), pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(), works
      pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => SomePage(),
      transitionsBuilder: (_, a, __, c) => FadeTransition(opacity: a, child: c)
    );
  }
  // Unknown route
  return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => UnknownPage());
},
```

Comment: It worked for me. The only thing I would add is the `settings` needs to be passed to the `PageRouteBuilder` constructor so the route arguments are included. Here is what I ended up with:
```
 onGenerateRoute: (settings) => PageRouteBuilder(
        pageBuilder: (context, _, __) => routes[settings.name](context),
        settings: settings,
        transitionsBuilder: (_, animation1, __, child) => FadeTransition(opacity: animation1, child: child),
      ),
```

Comment: Also, if you set `routes` on `MaterialApp` it seems to ignore `onGenerateRoute`

Comment: If I use this, the url at the top no longer seems to show the new route name.  Isn't that an issue if I want to say use pushNamedAndRemoveUntil()?

Comment: This is the simplest and best answer on how to setup a minimal page transition.  Simple is good.  Thank you.

Comment: It breaks the feel of the app though, sometimes you want to push from right sometimes you want to fade..

Answer (score 3):

I found an easy solution (inspired from [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65778648/16290110))

First, you need to set a static GlobalKey for MaterialApp and export it

```
static GlobalKey mtAppKey = GlobalKey();

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    key: MyApp.mtAppKey,
    ...
```

Also, you need to a custom PageRouteBuilder to handle it

Null-safety disabled

```
class CustomNamedPageTransition extends PageRouteBuilder {
  CustomNamedPageTransition(
    GlobalKey materialAppKey,
    String routeName, {
    Object arguments,
  }) : super(
          settings: RouteSettings(
            arguments: arguments,
            name: routeName,
          ),
          pageBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
          ) {
            assert(materialAppKey.currentWidget != null);
            assert(materialAppKey.currentWidget is MaterialApp);
            var mtapp = materialAppKey.currentWidget as MaterialApp;
            var routes = mtapp.routes;
            assert(routes.containsKey(routeName));
            return routes[routeName](context);
          },
          transitionsBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
            Widget child,
          ) =>
              FadeTransition(
            opacity: animation,
            child: child,
          ),
          transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
        );
}
```

Null-safety enabled

```
class CustomNamedPageTransition extends PageRouteBuilder {
  CustomNamedPageTransition(
    GlobalKey materialAppKey,
    String routeName, {
    Object? arguments,
  }) : super(
          settings: RouteSettings(
            arguments: arguments,
            name: routeName,
          ),
          pageBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
          ) {
            assert(materialAppKey.currentWidget != null);
            assert(materialAppKey.currentWidget is MaterialApp);
            var mtapp = materialAppKey.currentWidget as MaterialApp;
            var routes = mtapp.routes;
            assert(routes!.containsKey(routeName));
            return routes![routeName]!(context);
          },
          transitionsBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
            Widget child,
          ) =>
              FadeTransition(
            opacity: animation,
            child: child,
          ),
          transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
        );
}
```

Then, you can open your named route with

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  CustomNamedPageTransition(
    MyApp.mtAppKey,
    MyRoute.routeName,
  ),
);
```

or

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
  context,
  CustomNamedPageTransition(
    MyApp.mtAppKey,
    MyRoute.routeName,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using animated routes is possible without `onGenerateRoute`!

If you are using `MaterialApp`'s `routes` map for defining your named routes, here is how you could define a named route (whose name will not be `null`).

Just create your route by extending `PageRouteBuilder`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FadeInRoute extends PageRouteBuilder {
  final Widget page;

  FadeInRoute({this.page, String routeName})
      : super(
          settings: RouteSettings(name: routeName),            // set name here
          pageBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
          ) =>
              page,
          transitionsBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
            Widget child,
          ) =>
              FadeTransition(
            opacity: animation,
            child: child,
          ),
          transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        );
}
```

and then when you are navigating, just do:

```
Navigator.push( // or pushReplacement, if you need that
  context,
  FadeInRoute(
    routeName: RouteNames.home,
    page: MyHomeScreen(),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Can you explain how do you pass argument `FadeInRoute` in `Navigator.pushNamed` as second parameter when `String` is expected?

Comment: @MikeKokadii I think @Alexandar meant to use `Navigator.push()`.
This method is great for transitioning to a pre-determined widget at a given routeName. However, you need to provide the Widget for that page yourself. If you are looking for an easy way to make a nice transition replacement for `Navigator.pushNamed(....)` this is not it.

Comment: @Max thank you for pointing that out! It was definitely a mistake. In my original code, I used `pushReplacement` so I probably mis-read it when I was writing this. The answer is now edited :)

Comment: @MikeKokadii please check if this works for you now :)

Comment: @Aleksandar this class can do the `Navigator.pop` too? I'm calling my Fade class on `pop` like this: `Navigator.pop(context, FadeInRoute());`

Comment: @KayaRyuuna the second argument to `pop` is the "result of the navigation", i.e. the return value of the `await`ed `push`. See [the docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pop.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an animated transition and using `popUntil` with named routes **does not** require the use of `onGenerateRoute`. You only need to specify the `routeName` again when creating the `PageRouteBuilder`.

Modifying the example from the Flutter [docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/animation/page-route-animation), maintaining a named reference to a route can be achieved by adding the `settings` parameter to `PageRouteBuilder`:

```
Route _createRoute() {
  return PageRouteBuilder(
    settings: RouteSettings(name: '/new-screen'),
    pageBuilder: (context, animation, _) => const NewScreen(),
    transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, _, child) {
      const begin = Offset(0.0, 1.0);
      const end = Offset.zero;
      const curve = Curves.ease;

      var tween = Tween(begin: begin, end: end).chain(CurveTween(curve: curve));

      return SlideTransition(
        position: animation.drive(tween),
        child: child,
      );
    },
  );
}
```

which is simply called using `Navigator.of(context).push(_createRoute())`;

The screen `NewScreen` can be normally registered under the `MaterialApp` routes:

```
 MaterialApp(
 ...
 ...
   routes: {
     ...
     '/new-screen': (context) => NewScreen(),
   }
 )
```

You can modify the code above to be more dynamic.
That said, using `onGeneratedRoute` is a more permanent solution

Answer (score 0):

use the following code to animate named route in flutter

first build the transition animation:

```
class SizeTransitionAnimation extends PageRouteBuilder {
final Widget page;
 SizeTransitionAnimation({required this.page})
  : super(
      pageBuilder: (context, animation, anotherAnimation) => page,
      transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
      reverseTransitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, anotherAnimation, child) {
        animation = CurvedAnimation(
            parent: animation,
            curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
            reverseCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);
        return ScaleTransition(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          scale: animation,
          child: child,
        );
      },
    );
```

}

for me i used OnGenerateRoute as the following:

```
class RouteGenerator {
static Route<dynamic> generatedRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
switch (settings.name) {
  case MainScreen.routeName:
    return SizeTransitionAnimation(
      page: MainScreen(),
    );
  case ProductDetailsScreen.routeName:
    return SizeTransitionAnimation(
      page: ProductDetailsScreen(),
    );
  default:
    return _errorRoute();
}
```

}