# How to animate routes transtion relative to the previous one in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-routes

I am trying to achieve something like that coupertino page transition on routing. (briefly how to target and animate both the previous and current routes).

I checked this package [page_transition](https://pub.dev/packages/page_transition), but the logic used seems off as its rebuilding the previous context widget and tries to hack an animation in the new route.

even in the documentation it seems to only be about the route on top of the navigation stack.

and you end up with something like this:

```dart
 Navigator.of(context).push(AnimatedRoute(
                      prevPage: widget, nextPage: Page2()));
```

```dart
class AnimatedRoute extends PageRouteBuilder {

  final Widget nextPage;
  final Widget prevPage;

  AnimatedRoute({this.prevPage, this.nextPage}) : super(
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 700),
    pageBuilder: (
      BuildContext context,
      Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
    ) {
      return nextPage;
    },
    maintainState: true,
    transitionsBuilder: (
      BuildContext context,
      Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
      Widget child,
    ) {
      return Material(
        child: Stack(
          overflow: Overflow.visible,
          children: <Widget>[
            SlideTransition(
              position: Tween<Offset>(
                begin: const Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                end: const Offset(-0.3, 0.0),
              ).animate(animation),
              child: prevPage,
            ),

            SlideTransition(
              position: Tween<Offset>(
                begin: const Offset(1.0, 0.0),
                end: Offset.zero,
              ).animate(animation),
              child: AnimatedBuilder(
                animation: animation,
                builder: (c, w) {
                  return Material(
                    shadowColor: Colors.black,
                    // elevation: 10.0 * animation.value,
                    child: nextPage
                  );
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  );
}
```

apart from the rebuild this also doesn't take in account the state of the older widget.

a better way to handle that is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PageRouteBuilder` to be able to handle transition both for the page you are transitioning from and the one you are transitioning to as I explain below:

Note: `pageBuilder` takes 3 parameters:
context, animation and secondaryAnimation. `animation` is used when the page is navigated to and `secondaryAnimation` is used for when the page is navigated from.

Suppose that we have two pages, A and B.

For page A:

```dart
Navigator.of(context).push(
  PageRouteBuilder(
    pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) {
      return AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: animation,
        builder: (context, child) {
          return AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: secondaryAnimation,
            builder: (context, innerChild) {
              retrun Transform.scale(
                scale: (animation.value - secondaryAnimation.value),
                child: A(),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

And for page B:

```dart
Navigator.of(context).push(
  PageRouteBuilder(
    pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) {
      return AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: animation,
        builder: (context, child) {
          return AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: secondaryAnimation,
            builder: (context, child) {
              return Transform.translate(
                offset: Offset(
                  1.0 - animation.value,
                  0.0,
                ),
                child: B(),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

This will lead to a transition like the gif below:

[Transition sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hX4uBcbPTSEWX1zmYf2IsJMtuN95YID_/view?usp=sharing)

(gif explanation: first page moves out with scaling down and second page comes in like a slide transition)

Comment: could you kindly share a working example of your code

Comment: also use 3 dummy pages, i am seeing some glitches while pushing named routes

Comment: @bihireboris here is how you can handle it with named routes:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56792479/flutter-animate-transition-to-named-route

Comment: I actually found [one working example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60329585/10238136)...thought I still think that that`secondaryAnimation` should be handled on the top route that you are pushing...being on the previous route makes it harder to make dynamic

Comment: @bihireboris This though is about Flutter APIs, we can't do something about it I think.
Anyway if my answer was useful to you I would be happy for an upvote.

Comment: sure+1, though you should add that working example link or add your own to your answer, It'd help

Comment: @bihireboris Sure I will

Answer (score 0):

There are other packages too like you can use getx although it is bloated with features, but still it also has a lot of transition to apply b/w both pages. You can check their source code too if you want.

Also why not you use Cupertino Transition it is great and supported by flutter?

Comment: I need my head around on how they are animating both routes for custom animations also coupertino routing doesn't provide a lot of customization